# retriving values from the dynamically added textboxes in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am asp.net beginner,I am developing one website in which i want to add or remove text boxes dynamically as required (on click event of hyperlink). And on submit button i want to count the number of text boxes created,retrieve their values and dump this data in database.

I have used following java script to add the textboxes--

```
function addTxtBx()
{
         var txtBxHolder = document.getElementById('MyDiv');
         var txtdiv = document.createElement('div');
         txtdiv.setAttribute("id", "MyD1");
         var newTxtBx1 = document.createElement('input');

         newTxtBx1.type = 'text';


         newTxtBx1.setAttribute("id", "MyText1");



         txtdiv.appendChild(newTxtBx1);


         txtBxHolder.appendChild(txtdiv);

}

function removeTxtBx() 
{
         var allTxtBxs = document.getElementById('MyDiv').getElementsByTagName('div');
         if (allTxtBxs.length == 0) 
         {
             alert('there are no text boxes to remove');
         }
         else 
         {
             document.getElementById('MyDiv').removeChild(allTxtBxs[allTxtBxs.length -     1]);

         } 
}
```

And to access the values used following code on button click

```
TextBox textbox = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("MyText1"); 
string val = textbox.Text;
```

But it is not working.
Am i doing something wrong????
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose when you assign the name to test box

```
txtdiv.setAttribute("name", "dynamictextfield");
```

now fetch it as

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getValues(objName)
    {  
        var arr = new Array();
        arr = document.getElementsByName(objName);

        alert("total objects with name \"dynamictextfield\" = \n" + arr.length);

        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            var obj = document.getElementsByName(objName).item(i);
            alert(obj.id + " =  " + obj.value);
        }
    }

    </script>
```

refer http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-getElementsByName-Example.aspx